# Retornar o primeiro dia útil do mÊs

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho o seguinte script e gostaria que ele executasse apenas no primeiro dia útil de cada mês, como posso fazer?

```
var ritm = new GlideRecord('sc_req_item');
    ritm.addQuery('short_description', 'Rotina de Manutenção Preventiva');
    ritm.addQuery('state', '!=', 3).addCondition('state','!=',6).addCondition('state','!=',8);
    ritm.query();

    if(!ritm.next()){
        ritm.initialize(); 
        ritm.description = 'Solicitação aberta para a Realização da Manutenção Preventiva';
        ritm.short_description = 'Rotina de Manutenção Preventiva';
        ritm.u_qs_requested_for = '6816f79cc0a8016401c5a33be04be441';
        ritm.opened_by = '6816f79cc0a8016401c5a33be04be441';

        ritm.insert(); //insert record
    }else{
        ritm.u_fora_do_prazo=true;
        ritm.update();
    }
```

Comment: Só para confirmar, tem certeza se isso é JavaScript mesmo?

Comment: Sim, só preciso executar isso se o dia for o primeiro dia útil. 
Então preciso de uma verificação que retorne o primeiro dia útil do mês e se for o primeiro dia útil, executo o código acima

Comment: Essa é uma implementação complicada, ainda pode ocorrer da segunda ser um feriado. Se você quiser uma verificação extra para garantir que seja o primeiro dia útil do mês, coloque mais uma validação se esse dia não é feriado, com uma tabela de feriados, porque além dos feriados nacionais e mundial esses feriados podem ser diferentes em cada cidade.

Comment: Eu só preciso validar dia útil da semana, sem precisar saber se é feriado. 
Apenas executar se o dia for o primeiro dia útil do mês

Comment: Não creio que o JS vá conseguir lhe dizer quando é ou não feriado, nem mesmo em back-end, provavelmente vai ter que ter uma "base de dados".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o método `Date()` para poder retornar uma data completa e depois usar o método `getDay()` para poder pegar apenas o dia da semana:

**Parte 1**

```
let data = new Date();
let dia = data.getDay();
```

Depois opcionalmente você pode armazenar todos os dias da semana como `String` em um `Array` e depois fazer uma comparação se a `dataformatada` (no qual contêm todos os dias da semana) `[dia]` (no qual contêm o dia da semana atual) for igual a string `Segunda` então execute o que estiver dentro do comando `if`:

**Parte 2**

```
let dataformatada = ["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", 
"Sabádo"];

if (dataformatada[dia] == "Segunda") {
    // Aqui vai o código a ser executado!
}
```

**Parte 3**

```js
        let data = new Date();
        let dia = data.getDay();

        let dataformatada = ["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sabádo"];

        if (dataformatada[dia] == "Segunda") {
            var ritm = new GlideRecord('sc_req_item');
            ritm.addQuery('short_description', 'Rotina de Manutenção Preventiva');
            ritm.addQuery('state', '!=', 3).addCondition('state','!=',6).addCondition('state','!=',8);
            ritm.query();

            if(!ritm.next()){
                ritm.initialize(); 
                ritm.description = 'Solicitação aberta para a Realização da Manutenção Preventiva';
                ritm.short_description = 'Rotina de Manutenção Preventiva';
                ritm.u_qs_requested_for = '6816f79cc0a8016401c5a33be04be441';
                ritm.opened_by = '6816f79cc0a8016401c5a33be04be441';

                ritm.insert(); //insert record
            }else{
                ritm.u_fora_do_prazo=true;
                ritm.update();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Não entendi o `if (dataformatada[dia] == "Segunda") {`... nem sempre o primeiro dia útil do mês é uma segunda-feira.

Comment: Opa! esqueci de acrescentar alguns coisas, vou editar novamente minha resposta.

Answer (score 1):

O método getDay() do objeto Date retorna um numero entre 0 e 6, sendo 0 domingo e 6 sábado.

Assim voce pode testar se é sábado ou domingo.

Já saber se é feriado ou não, só mantendo uma tabela mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Se não importa saber se o primeiro "dia útil" do mês é feriado, então você quer apenas saber se hoje não é nem sábado nem domingo, pois esses dois dias, sendo feriado ou não, não são dias úteis, ou seja, quer pegar o primeiro dia do mês que seja de segunda a sexta-feira.

Você pode fazer isto da forma abaixo, comparando o dia atual com o primeiro dia do mês explicado acima.

Primeiro você cria um objeto `Date()` para pegar a data atual:

```
var hoje = new Date();
```

Em seguida outro objeto `Date()` para pegar o dia 1 do mês atual:

```
var pri_dia_util = new Date(hoje.getFullYear(), hoje.getMonth(), 1);
```

Aí você pega o dia da semana do objeto acima:

```
var dia_semana = pri_dia_util.getDay();
```

Faz um `while` até que o valor `dia_semana` seja diferente de 0 (domingo) ou 6 (sábado). Se já for diferente, o `while` passa direto:

```
while(dia_semana == 0 || dia_semana == 6){
   pri_dia_util.setDate(pri_dia_util.getDate() + 1);
   dia_semana = pri_dia_util.getDay();
}
```

> Se o primeiro dia do mês for sábado ou domingo, o `while` vai incrementando o objeto
>   `pri_dia_util` +1 dia até que seja segunda-feira.

E finalmente você compara o dia atual com o dia resultante do objeto `pri_dia_util`:

```
if(hoje == pri_dia_util){
   // executar código
}
```

O código todo ficará assim:

```
var hoje = new Date();
var pri_dia_util = new Date(hoje.getFullYear(), hoje.getMonth(), 1);
var dia_semana = pri_dia_util.getDay();

while(dia_semana == 0 || dia_semana == 6){
   pri_dia_util.setDate(pri_dia_util.getDate() + 1);
   dia_semana = pri_dia_util.getDay();
}

if(hoje == pri_dia_util){
   // executar código
}
```

---

Se você fizer um teste com o mês de setembro, onde o dia 1 caiu num domingo, o valor de `pri_dia_util` será o dia 2 (segunda-feira). Veja:

```js
var hoje = new Date();
var pri_dia_util = new Date(2019, 8, 1);
var dia_semana = pri_dia_util.getDay();

while(dia_semana == 0 || dia_semana == 6){
   pri_dia_util.setDate(pri_dia_util.getDate() + 1);
   dia_semana = pri_dia_util.getDay();
}

console.log(pri_dia_util.toLocaleDateString());

if(hoje == pri_dia_util){
   // executar código
}
```

Da mesma forma o mês de dezembro/2019, onde o dia 1 cai num domingo, segunda-feira será o dia 2:

```js
var hoje = new Date();
var pri_dia_util = new Date(2019, 11, 1);
var dia_semana = pri_dia_util.getDay();

while(dia_semana == 0 || dia_semana == 6){
   pri_dia_util.setDate(pri_dia_util.getDate() + 1);
   dia_semana = pri_dia_util.getDay();
}

console.log(pri_dia_util.toLocaleDateString());

if(hoje == pri_dia_util){
   // executar código
}
```

Já no mês atual (novembro/2019) irá retornar o próprio dia 1, pois caiu numa sexta-feira:

```js
var hoje = new Date();
var pri_dia_util = new Date(hoje.getFullYear(), hoje.getMonth(), 1);
var dia_semana = pri_dia_util.getDay();

while(dia_semana == 0 || dia_semana == 6){
   pri_dia_util.setDate(pri_dia_util.getDate() + 1);
   dia_semana = pri_dia_util.getDay();
}

console.log(pri_dia_util.toLocaleDateString());

if(hoje == pri_dia_util){
   // executar código
}
```

Já em junho/2019, o primeiro dia caiu num sábado, logo a segunda-feira foi o dia 3:

```js
var hoje = new Date();
var pri_dia_util = new Date(2019, 5, 1);
var dia_semana = pri_dia_util.getDay();

while(dia_semana == 0 || dia_semana == 6){
   pri_dia_util.setDate(pri_dia_util.getDate() + 1);
   dia_semana = pri_dia_util.getDay();
}

console.log(pri_dia_util.toLocaleDateString());

if(hoje == pri_dia_util){
   // executar código
}
```

Comment: Show, deu certo. 
Obrigado pelo apoio

Comment: Blz. Se resolveu é preciso marcar ✔️ na resposta.